# How do I reply to comments from admin panel on a tablet PC?

Tags: comments

For certain reasons I prefer to reply to readers' comments from the admin panel (edit-comments.php). It's not a problem with a mouse. When I place the cursor over a comment, the comment management links pop-up, including the reply option. It's shown below, albeit with the Russian UI.

[image: comment management]

The Reply link opens the reply form right below the comment.

It doesn't work that way for me on a tablet PC. I can place a finger on the comment and the links appear, but when I try to press any link they all disappear.

FWIW, I have an HP tablet and use IE10 (metro/desktop) on Windows 8, and have no desire to change the browser.

Basically, there are two questions:

1. Is there an obvious option I'm missing that enables me to accomplish the goal?
2. If not, how can I modify WP behavior to display these links permanently?

Thanks for your attention to my questions :)

Comment: By default, hover functionality should work with a click instead on touch devices.  You may be a hardware/browser edge case that hasn't been addressed by core.  I ran quick numbers on analytics for a few sites I manage and the highest IE on a windows mobile device percentage of views was 0.3%.

Comment: Andrew, like I said, touching the comment invokes the links, but then I can't press them, because they disappear. I'm not surprised by the stats, but they are irrelevant to my question :)

Answer (score 0):

For IPad and iPhone there is an app called Touch Punch that makes the admin screens more tablet friendly.  Maybe there is something similar to resolve your issue?

Comment: Thanks, Ian. After some research: there's a WP app for Windows Phone from Automattic, but their version of modern app for Windows 8 requires Jetpack plug-in and connecting the self-hosted blog to wordpress.com, which I'm not really willing to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an option you're missing, but this can be used as a workaround:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Show Quick Actions for Devices
 */

foreach( array( 'edit.php', 'edit-comments.php' ) as $page )
    add_action( "admin_head-$page", 'hide_row_action_wpse_112889', 100 );

function hide_row_action_wpse_112889() 
{
    if( !wp_is_mobile() )
        return;

    echo '<style type="text/css">.row-actions {visibility:initial;}</style>';
}
```

The function [`wp_is_mobile`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/vars.php#L106) can be replaced with [another detection method](https://github.com/cbschuld/Browser.php).

At the end, this may be more effective than having to "hover" (not) and then selecting the action.

List of files where `row_actions` shows up:

[image: row-actions files list]

Comment: Thanks, this looks close! Unlike IE on Windows Phone (which does display the links I need right away), modern IE10 on Windows 8 doesn't report itself as a mobile browser. Yet it does add "Touch" on touch capable hardware to the user agent string [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/07/12/ie10-user-agent-string-update.aspx] Is this possible to modify your code to take advantage of this fact? Unfortunately, my PHP skills are close to zero, I'm just a blogger :)

Comment: You'd have to create a custom function to detect browser and platform using the [`Browser` class](https://github.com/cbschuld/Browser.php/blob/master/lib/Browser.php#L56). Or use some custom JavaScript and place it in that `admin_head` hook.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to my question #2

> how can I modify WP behavior to display these links permanently?

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Always Show Quick Actions
 */

add_action( "admin_head", 'hide_row_action_wpse_112889');

function hide_row_action_wpse_112889() 
{
    echo '<style type="text/css">.row-actions {visibility:visible !important;}</style>';
}
?>
```

It does the trick, and the plugin can be quickly disabled if these links start getting on your nerves :)